# Filter by date in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I am trying to filter the delivery instruction table by date. Especially only in Delivery Instructions, table data will be removed after 7 days after the creation. So in its model, I used DateTimeField as a date-time format. But in other models (e.g Part), I used DateField, and in views.py I write the same function as below and it works. But the issue with Delivery instructions is filtered by date is not working.

filters.py

```
class DIFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created_date = django_filters.CharFilter( widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD'}))
    class Meta:
        model = DeliveryIns
        fields = ['product','supplier', 'created_date']
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        if self.request.GET.get('supplier'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(supplier_id=self.request.GET.get('supplier'))
        elif self.request.GET.get('product'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(product_id=self.request.GET.get('product'))
            
        elif self.request.GET.get('created_date'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_date=self.request.GET['created_date'])

        return queryset

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = DIFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        DeliveryIns._base_manager.filter(created_date__lt=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=7)).delete()
        return context
```

models.py

```
class DeliveryIns(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Part(models.Model): 
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Can anyone help me out what's the matter? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the field which you change the behaviour in Meta.fields
Instead you can do this:

```
from django_filters import DateFilter

created_data = DateFilter(field_name, lookup_expr="exact")
```